# Images are blurry in one category and not the other

Tags: css, images, image-size

You can see what I mean if you check out the site:

http://healthitlink-e8865038.cloudapp.net

All the images in the Apple/iOS category are blurry but if you click over to page 5 you'll see the Android images are very crisp & clear.

On another template the images were being sized at 100x100 - so the Android and the Apple images were the same - the all looked great.

I'm wondering - is there a way to make just the posts in the Apple/iOS category - and all it's children categories, display at 100x100 while leaving the Android at 270x270?

Or, in your collective opinions, should I just change all the images to 100x100? It would certainly give me more room to play with on the front page ;)

But it's an interesting problem that can probably be dealth with using some CSS magic - which is what it is to me, magic…so any advice?

Thanks!
Robert

Comment: Unfortunately [coding](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and design questions are off-topic for this site. You might ask this over at the [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) site, but I'd recommend reviewing the FAQ in their Help Center first.

Comment: Make the images the largest they need and then scale them with @media triggers per device. Otherwise, you will see blurred stuff. This will be far easier than trying to make cache-gen per device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think css is going to help you for making the blurry ones clearer. Pretty much you have a lower resolution on the "blurry" images...anytime you blow it up, it will be blurry. Of course, since they are 100x100...you can indeed make the others that size as well to match (I think its too small though personally). Is there anyway you can just get a duplicate of the image but in a larger resolution?

As far as css for the two ways of implementing both sizes, of course there are ways, but from a user experience and UI perspective I wouldn't recommend it. It throws the user off visually. The more symmetrical and even things are, the easier on the eyes (your viewer) and the cleaner the design.

I tested out 55% of its original height and its not too blurry at that size
Just my 2cents :)

Comment: Thank you all - and Carine you were absolutely correct! For some reason the links Apple provides in their iTunes database does not include links to the larger, .png, images - just the smaller jpegs. Apologies for posting in the wrong spot.